# GWT: get class literal from String containing its name and path

Tags: java, string, class, reflection, gwt

I am working on a GWT project and I'd like to get the class literal (not the instance) from a string that contains its canonical name. I wish I could use the method Class.forname but unfortunately, as you know, this method is not available on JRE emulation.
Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: A class literal is a source code construct. Do you mean a `Class` object?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to generate this yourself - GWT will deliberately not permit it. In order for GWT to be able to provide this, it would need to compile in all possible classes (and interfaces) from the provided sources, it wouldn't be able to prune any unused code, since it cannot automatically understand which types you might possibly ask for.

Note that the same limitation will exist if you do want an instance of the class - you can't take a string and get an instance either, at least not without some lookup mechanism.

--

Chances are you don't need this for very many types and can either generate it by hand, or automatically, or mixing the approaches.

For example, if you only need access to a few of your own specific classes, perhaps you could annotate each with something like `@ClassLookup`, and create an Annotation Processor which collects them all and provides a `Map<String, Class<?>>` instance with the correct names and class instances.

If on the other hand you need some classes that you didn't write (and so, cannot annotate), it might be possible to make yet another annotation that lets you list the other classes you need, or you can copy the map above and generate your own entries:

```
// for example, assuming the processor generated the LookupCache type:
Map<String, Class<?>> map = LookupCache.getMap();
map.put("java.lang.Double", Double.class);
```